I can't program STM32F100RBTx to send pwm signals
I am trying to send PWM signals using STM32F100RBTx but it is not working. I double checked all the addresses but it is still the same. I wasn't sure if I was flashing at the beginning but I configured the PB7 pin to be GPIO output and connected to a LED and the LED is working so I can flash it and my GPIO conifgurations must be working. Here is the code, I don't know what to try:
TUFAN_VLDCMS_Global.h:
#include <stdint.h>

#define RCC         0x40021000
#define RCC_AHBENR  0x40021014
#define RCC_APB2ENR 0x40021018
#define RCC_APB1ENR 0x4002101C


#define AFIO        0x40010000
#define AFIO_MAPR   0x40010004


#define GPIOB       0x40010C00
#define GPIOB_ODR   0x40010C0C 


#define TIM4        0x40000800  
#define TIM4_CR1    0x40000800 
#define TIM4_CR2    0x40000804
#define TIM4_SMCR   0x40000808
#define TIM4_DIER   0x4000080C
#define TIM4_SR     0x40000810
#define TIM4_EGR    0x40000814
#define TIM4_CCMR1  0x40000818
#define TIM4_CCMR2  0x4000081C
#define TIM4_CCER   0x40000820
#define TIM4_CNT    0x40000824
#define TIM4_PSC    0x40000828
#define TIM4_ARR    0x4000082C
#define TIM4_CCR1   0x40000834
#define TIM4_CCR2   0x40000838
#define TIM4_CCR3   0x4000083C
#define TIM4_CCR4   0x40000840
#define TIM4_DCR    0x40000848
#define TIM4_DMAR   0x4000084C

main.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "TUFAN_VLDCMS_Global.h"



int main(){
    

     volatile uint32_t * tim4Cr1     =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_CR1;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Psc     =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_PSC;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Arr     =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_ARR;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Ccr1    =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_CCR1;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Ccmr1   =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_CCMR1;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Ccer    =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_CCER;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Egr     =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_EGR;


     volatile uint32_t * rccApb1enr  =  (volatile uint32_t *) RCC_APB1ENR;
     volatile uint32_t * rccApb2enr  =  (volatile uint32_t *) RCC_APB2ENR;

     
     
     volatile uint32_t * gpiobCrL    =  (volatile uint32_t *) GPIOB;
     volatile uint32_t * gpiobOdr    =  (volatile uint32_t *) GPIOB_ODR;

     volatile uint32_t * afioMapr    =  (volatile uint32_t *) AFIO_MAPR;

     *rccApb1enr    |= (1<<2);     //enable TIM4 from APB1
     *rccApb2enr    |= (1<<0);     //enable AFIO from APB2
     *rccApb2enr    |= (1<<3);     //enable IOPB from APB2

     *afioMapr      &= ~(1<<12);   //set alternate function remap to 0

     *gpiobCrL      |= (3<<24);    //PB6 Output Mode 50Mhz
     *gpiobCrL      |= (2<<26);    //PB6 Alternate function Push-Pull
     
     *gpiobCrL      |= (3<<28);    //Configuring PB7 to for test to see if i can flash it
     *gpiobCrL      &= ~(3<<30);   

     *tim4Cr1       |= 0x0000;     //reseting it just in case 
     *tim4Psc       =  7;          //calculated it thinking default clock speed is 8MHz
     *tim4Arr       =  62;         //I want to have PWM signal around 16kHz
     *tim4Ccr1      =  31;         //and %50 duty cycle

     *tim4Ccmr1     |= 0x68;       //configuring channel 1
     *tim4Ccer      |= (1<<0);     //enabling channel 1

     *tim4Cr1       |= (1<<0);     //enable the timer
     *tim4Egr       |= (1<<0);

     while (1){
       
          *tim4Ccr1      =  31;
          *gpiobOdr      |= (1<<7);
     }
     
}


I don't know what you think this does, but it doesn't: *tim4Cr1 |= 0x0000;

@pmacfarlane It because I want it to reset the register before I write anything into it. is that wrong?

Logical OR with zero does nothing. It does not set any bits, nor does it clear any bits.

@pmacfarlane Oh, you're right my mistake.

@pmacfarlane I fixed it now. But still not working.

What actually isn't working? What do you expect to see, and what do you actually see?

@pmacfarlane I want to have a 16kHz pwm signal from CH1 of TIM4 but there is no output

I'd suggest to use the debugger to validate if TIM4 is actually running and if it is configured correctly. Just start your code, then pause it, go to peripherals/SFR and see if TIM4's CNT is changing when you run/pause your code. Maybe check all the TIM4 registers and verify all their fields are in expected values. Like UDIS, URS, OPM are not set, SMS=0. See if CC1IF flag has been set (i.e. compare value ever matched the counter).

@AndreyTurkin Hey! I am a student and new to embedded programming. Do you have any suggestions to learn how to use debuggers like gdb , what article should I read etc. I would highly appricate it.

I don't know your setup so cannot really tell you how to do it. I use STM32CubeIDE and it has this handy view of peripheral registers, with each register broken down to its fields. Other IDEs like Keil would have something similar. Raw gdb - not so much, but you can still use it to check the register values if you really want to. Can't really go into discussion on how to start using  on SO but the Internet is filled with tutorials on pretty much all of them.

I'd strongly advise using the ST provided stm32f1xx.h header rather than laboriously defining your own register addresses.

@Clifford I just enjoy it like that.

Perhaps, but now you are asking others to check your work, so making work for others not just yourself.

@Clifford I cheked it like 12321313 times. And I do not ask you to check if register address is correct  I am asking if am I writing to right registers or should I write into diffrent register etc. You don't have to be rude.

You have missed my point, and misinterpreted my intent as rudeness.  I am not trying to fix your problem, but giving advice that might help avoid such problems in the future.   It was advice only, take it or leave it. It will improve your productivity, and the greater familiarity will increase your audience for such questions, so you are more likely to get an answer.  You may have checked the values, but still it does not work.  It is not just the register addresses, but all the values you are masking that must be correct, and that is a series of magic numbers all to be verified.

@Clifford sorry, I was struggling with the code and I am trying to understand how the mcu works so I thought one by one writing the registers would be more effective way to learn instead of just saying this libary will do for me. So I might misunderstood you.

Fair enough, but I was not proposing using any library (the abysmal STM32Cube especially).  The header file is a set of register address macros and structures for accessing peripheral registers, and bit masks and other definitions for accessing bit fields within registers.  At its simplest you would simply be replacing your *gpiobCrL with GPIOB->CRL for example.

The problem with:
*gpiobCrL      |= (3<<24);   //PB6 Output Mode 50Mhz
*gpiobCrL      |= (2<<26);   //PB6 Alternate function Push-Pull
     
*gpiobCrL      |= (3<<28);   
*gpiobCrL      &= ~(3<<30);

is that the reset state of GPIOx_CRL is 0x44444444 and not zero:
(0x44444444 | (3<<24) | (2<<26) | (3<<28)) & ~(3<<30) == 0x3F444444

The part (2<<26) does not clear bit 26 which is 1 in the reset state, so you end up with CNF6 == 3.  To set CNF6 == 2 you need:
*gpiobCrL      &= ~(3<<26);  // Clear CNF6 bits
*gpiobCrL      |= (2<<26);   // PB6 Alternate function Push-Pull

((0x44444444 & ~(3<<26)) | (3<<24) | (2<<26) | (3<<28)) & ~(3<<30) == 0x3B444444
             ^^^^^^^^^^


Thank you. As a student this piece of code tought me a lot about registers, their reset states, how to read datasheets and how to use debuggers from terminal like openocd and gdb. I hope you'll have great day!

After @AndreyTurkin's answer, I learned how to look at memory addresses with OpenOCD and realized the GPIOB_CRL register has a different value than what I wrote into it. I solved the problem by writing *gpiobCrL = 0x3B444444;, but I still have no clue why the previous method didn't work.
     *gpiobCrL      |= (3<<24);   //PB6 Output Mode 50Mhz
     *gpiobCrL      |= (2<<26);   //PB6 Alternate function Push-Pull
     
     *gpiobCrL      |= (3<<28);   
     *gpiobCrL      &= ~(3<<30);

When I write it like this at the top, it irrelevantly opens the PB4 pin. If anyone knows why this happens and let me know, it would be highly appreciated.
After all my TUFAN_VLDCMS_Global.h file was not have any incorrect registers. so I don't share it here I didn't change anything in the file. But Here is the main.c file;
main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "TUFAN_VLDCMS_Global.h"



int main(){
    

     volatile uint32_t * tim4Cr1     =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_CR1;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Psc     =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_PSC;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Arr     =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_ARR;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Ccr1    =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_CCR1;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Ccmr1   =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_CCMR1;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Ccer    =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_CCER;
     volatile uint32_t * tim4Egr     =  (volatile uint32_t *) TIM4_EGR;


     volatile uint32_t * rccApb1enr  =  (volatile uint32_t *) RCC_APB1ENR;
     volatile uint32_t * rccApb2enr  =  (volatile uint32_t *) RCC_APB2ENR;

     
     
     volatile uint32_t * gpiobCrL    =  (volatile uint32_t *) GPIOB;
     volatile uint32_t * gpiobOdr    =  (volatile uint32_t *) GPIOB_ODR;

     volatile uint32_t * afioMapr    =  (volatile uint32_t *) AFIO_MAPR;

     
     *rccApb2enr    |= (1<<0);      //enable AFIO from APB2
     *rccApb2enr    |= (1<<3);      //enable IOPB from APB2
     *rccApb1enr    |= (1<<2);      //enable TIM4 from APB1   

     *afioMapr      &= ~(1<<12);      //set alternate function remap to 0

     *gpiobCrL    = 0x3B444444;

     //this doesn't work I dont know why yet
     /* *gpiobCrL      |= (3<<24);   //PB6 Output Mode 50Mhz
     *gpiobCrL      |= (2<<26);   //PB6 Alternate function Push-Pull

     *gpiobCrL      |= (3<<28);   
     *gpiobCrL      &= ~(3<<30);  */  

     
     *tim4Psc       =  7;
     *tim4Arr       =  62;
     *tim4Ccr1      =  0;

     *tim4Ccmr1    =  0x0000;
     *tim4Ccmr1    |= (3<<5);
     *tim4Ccmr1    |= (1<<3);

     *tim4Ccer     |= (1<<0);

     
    

     while (1){
          *tim4Cr1       |= (1<<0);
          *tim4Ccr1      =  30;
          *gpiobOdr      |= (1<<7);
     }
     
}


I think I can't tag people to answers so I want to thank @AndreyTurkin if he sees it from here.
